# How to read and overwrite all *.txt files in a folder with python and bs4?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup, scope

I have a folder with thousands of files. I'm attempting to parse the XML tag in them using beautifulsoup4.

I'm able to do it for each file individually but can't make my script work using a for loop.

Here's my code so far:

```js
import bs4 as bs
import glob


path = r"~/Desktop/pythontest/*.txt"
files = glob.glob(path)

# ------------------------READ AND PARSE TEXT-----------------------------------------


for f in files:
    # open file in read mode
    source = open(f, "rt")

    # parse xml as soup
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    soupText = soup.get_text()
    text = soupText.replace(r"\n", " ")

    # close file
    source.close()


# --------------------------OVERWRITE FILE---------------------------------------------
for f in files:
    # open file in write mode
    source = open(f, "wt")

    # overwrite the file with the soup
    source.write((text))
    # # close file
    source.close()

print(text)
```

When I run it the console gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./camltest.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(text)
NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

I suspect this is a scope problem but can't fix it. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: But it won't make the script work either way no?

Comment: You aren't storing text anywhere.

Comment: Think carefully about your logic. You propose to open *each* file one at a time, determine the `text`, and use the *same* variable to store the result... what do you expect to end up in `text` at the end of this process? Then, you propose to open *each* file again one at a time, then use *what was in `text`* to write the new file. You should expect every file to end up with the same data, right? So, maybe you can think of a way to address that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply read and then write to the file in the same loop.

```
for f in files:
    source = open(f, "w+")
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    soupText = soup.get_text()
    text = soupText.replace(r"\n", " ")
    source.write(text)
    source.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, using only one for loop solved the problem (I wasn't storing any variable as pointed in the above comments). I had to open() twice though with the "r" and then "w" flag as beautiful couldn't read with the "w+" flag for some reason. But it does the job. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Note that `text` is defined inside your first for loop.

If `files` is an empty list, `text` will never be defined.

Comment: Not sure to understand. The files path point to 5 .txt files, it should be defined no?

Comment: Did you verify that `files` contains what you expect it to contain? Did you try checking what `text` ends up as, *immediately after the part that sets it*?